# ModuleNotFoundError pycharm

Tags: django, pycharm, interpreter

Whenever i try to import any package that i installed previously i get following error. I can't figure out what i did wrong.

```
C:\Users\David\Documents\Django_directory\usws15\eRoutes>python manage.py runserver 8002
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x000001FF0416A6A8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 397, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 536, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 529, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
......
"C:\Users\David\Documents\Django_directory\usws15\eRoutes\routing\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "C:\Users\David\Documents\Django_directory\usws15\eRoutes\routing\views.py", line 2, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

[image: Project interpreter]

Comment: What @shadow said. You can click the green run play icon to save yourself keystrokes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your virtualenv is activated.

You can tell that you don't have it activated by looking at the path in your stacktrace. All of the django stuff should be coming out of your virtualenv directory.

Before you run any django commands, you need to run `venv\Scripts\activate.bat`. which activates your virtual python environment.

Once you've done this, you should find that your runserver command starts working.

---

Seeing as you are using pycharm - using the Terminal within it (rather than a presumed cmd session) should activate it for you automatically.